# How to get the total sum of all the 2nd fields with delimiter?

Tags: c++

I want to write code for getting the 2nd field of the entire text file and adding the total value of all the 2nd fields which are in numbers that may have decimal places. E.g of input file

```
 electricity:200:20jan2010 
 utilities:200:20jan2010
```

Prototype:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    while(getline(file, line)){
        stringstream linestream(line);
        string data1;
        double data2;
        string data3;
        getline(linestream, data1, ':');
        getline(linestream, data2, ':');
        /*how should i write the code to get the sum of 2nd field only*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help your question... This code generates all positive value and negative value , if you want it to be specific, remove either totalPositive or totalNegative to suit your requirement

```
std::ifstream file("Expense.txt");
std::string line;
double totalNegative = 0;
double totalPositive = 0;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    std::string data1;
    double data2;
    std::string data3;

    getline(linestream, data1, ':');
    linestream >> data2;

    if (data2 > 0)
        totalPositive += data2;
    else
        totalNegative =- data2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.  Not terribly efficient, but you can get the idea.

```
while(getline(file, line)){
    size_t pos;
    while ((pos=line.find(":"))!=string::npos) line.replace(pos,1," ");
    istringstream linestream(line);
    string data1;
    double data2;
    linestream >> data1 >> data2;
}
```

Also, here's a simple string tokenizer, which can handle this and more:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class string_tokenizer
{
  typedef std::string      str;
  typedef std::vector<str> seq;
  seq      m_Tokens;
  unsigned m_Current;
public:
  string_tokenizer(const str& s, const str& delim=" \t")
    : m_Current(0)
  {
    int p=-1;
    int len=s.length();
    while (true)
    {
      p=s.find_first_not_of(delim,p+1);
      if (p<0) break;
      int e=s.find_first_of(delim,p+1);
      if (e<0) e=len;
      m_Tokens.push_back(s.substr(p,e-p));
      p=e;
    }
  }

  typedef typename seq::const_iterator const_iterator;
  const_iterator begin() const { return m_Tokens.begin();  }
  const_iterator end()   const { return m_Tokens.end();    }

  unsigned size() const { return m_Tokens.size(); }
  bool     has_more_tokens() const { return m_Current<m_Tokens.size(); }
  str      get_next_token() 
  { 
    if (m_Current<m_Tokens.size()) return m_Tokens[m_Current++]; 
    return str("");
  }
};
```

Comment: Note: will fail as soon as something like `"sewer and garbage"` or anything else introducing whitespace before the first colon is used. Those colons are likely there for a reason.

Comment: Of course you're right.  I was only giving an example given the input above.  I usually use my own string tokenizer (Java inspired) for cases like this.

Comment: @WhozCraig,   you made me feel a little guilty, so I added my tokenizer.  :-)